# How do I get firmware for Broadcom 4306?

Tags: 11.10, broadcom

IT reads that I have Broadcom 4306 but firmware is missing.

Comment: Please view my post on this http://askubuntu.com/questions/103865/hp-broadcom-wireless-fix

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Plug in an ethernet cable, then use the Additional Drivers program.

- [How do I install additional drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47506/how-do-i-install-a-graphics-or-wireless-card-driver)

You can get to the 'Additional Drivers' application by clicking on the 'Gear' at the top right. Then selecting 'System Settings'. In the window that pops up, select 'Additional Drivers' under the Hardware heading.

You can also get there by opening a terminal and entering `sudo jockey-gtk`

I'm pretty sure the Broadcom STA driver will be the one you're looking for.